# Munchkin vs Munchkin Deluxe

Tags: munchkin

I'm debating between the two versions as it is only a few dollars difference. Would any of you who own the Deluxe version say this is worth it? The board piece sounds appealing but I hear the packaging box takes up a lot of space. I can't seem to find Deluxe copies in my area to compare the size and will have to order online.

My friends do have other packs such as Munchkin Cthulhu and its expansions, if that's helpful at all.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Board & Card Games SE! In its current form, your question is rather open and subjective. StackExchange focuses on questions that can be answered, preferrably with a single answer. Do you think you could rephrase your question so it focuses more on what the differences are (objective) and which consequences each difference has (probably objective), instead of whether or not those differences are worth it (subjective)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, table games that can be played without a gameboard tend to be played without the gameboard. In our group, we have Bang and Dixit for example, both came with nicely decorated boards that are now sitting in the "leftover parts" stack. The games can be played just as well without them, the required area to play is a bit smaller and more flexible. Oh, and the boxes are also lighter and smaller if we carry the games to another place to play there.

In my opinion you should go for the normal edition, except maybe if you only ever plan to play at home, on your huge table.

Comment: In my experience all parts of the game are used and boards in games like Dixit are always used as they help keep track of things and are smaller than the other parts of the game.

Comment: Somewhat related: in our games of Fluxx, we always leave the basic rules in the box, which saves us 7 and 133/256 square inches of table space.

Answer (score 6):

I own the deluxe addition and am very glad I bought it. The board gives a nice way to track the game and can easily be converted if you are going to use the optional Supermuchkin rules (advance to level 20 to win). Yes it can be done with paper and dice but I have kids and the board makes it easier for everyone to use.